# Python Discord Bot - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm new to python (and programming in general), and I'm making a discord bot that will help me with my school schedule. So I want to type like !schedule to get my schedule for the day. I have a link to a "API" that my friend made which is "https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/TE19?today=true".

Here's the code:

```
lessons = str('https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/TE19? 
today=true')
lessons = lessons.replace('och', '')
lessons = lessons.replace('}', '')
lessons = lessons.replace(']', '')
lessons = lessons.replace("'", '')
lessons = re.sub( '(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', ' ', lessons )
lessons1 = lessons.split(",")
```

And so I was also given this code by someone else:

```
async def response2():
embed = discord.Embed(
title = 'Schema',
description = '',
colour = discord.Colour.blue()
)
embed.set_author(name='Schoolsoft')
embed.add_field(name='1', value=lessons1[1], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='2', value=lessons1[2], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='3', value=lessons1[3], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='4', value=lessons1[4], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='5', value=lessons1[5], inline=False)
return embed
```

But it says "Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range", and I believe it's the value for lessons1 thats making it troublesome. I wrote the code below to call for this function:

```
@client.command(name='schema', help='This command returns schema')
async def schema(ctx):
# responses = schoolsoft_api.get_lessons(token, school, org_id)
#await ctx.send(r.text)
#embed.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
embed = await response2()
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I hope someone can help me with this since it would be really cool to get it work. What I basically want is that it will list everything from the link embedded instead of raw for a better look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might wanna check out the link to see what I mean, but yeah I somehow wanna print it on discord but a bit cleaner and nice look

Comment: you don't show the definition of lesson1 in this code. i notice that you start indexing by 1 (`lessons1[1]`). python arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1

Comment: Oh my bad, forgot to post my code, I will do it now

Comment: You do realize `lessons = str('https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/TE19? 
today=true')` makes lessons equal to `https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/TE19? 
today=true` right? You have to use a web scraper

Comment: How do I use a web scraper? Could you link me somewhere where I could learn about it?

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much means that you're trying to access a value at some index in the list that doesn't exists, explanation

```py
>>> some_random_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> some_random_list[0] # List indexes start at 0, not 1
1
>>> some_random_list[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm guessing you're getting the error when adding the fields to the embed in the `response2` function, make sure you didn't mess up the indexes and the list is of the correct length, you can also use a `try/except` block

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the link doesn't have any kind of lists... But is there any other way I could make a embedded message with the information from the website?

Comment: Well you're not actually doing the request, the `lessons1` variable looks something like this `['https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/ T E19?']`

Comment: Hm, I see. So I should replace the values for lessons1 with the link? ['https://apischoolsoft.herokuapp.com/v1/schedule/ T E19?']